# 421 Mailgun temporarily unavailable

Tags: mailgun

I keep getting this error message from Clickfunnels when trying to send emails through Mailgun '421 Mailgun temporarily unavailable'

Is this me or Mailgun - i have used this route of many occasions previously and this is the first time I have seen this